# How to display new JPanel from another classe?

Tags: java, swing

I'm new with Swing, I would like to display this (productList):
[image]

Into this (home):
[image]

Each ad that I have, I would like to display a new produt in my productList.

This is my code:

```java
  public class home {
    private JPanel panelMain;
    private JButton proposerUneAnnonceButton;
    private JComboBox comboBox1;
    private JComboBox comboBox2;
    private JTextField textField2;
    private JTextField textField3;
    private JButton rechercherButton;
    private JButton filtrerButton;
    private JPanel list;

    public JPanel home() {
        return this.panelMain;
    }

    public JPanel getPanelMain() {
        return panelMain;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("app");
        home home = new home();

        DDB mockDDB = new DDB();
        List<AnnonceEntity> annonces = mockDDB.getAnnonces(null,null,null,null,null); // Get all ad (just one actually)
        home.list=new JPanel();

        annonces.forEach(annonceEntity -> {
            //it's enter fine here
            ProductList prl = new ProductList(annonceEntity.getNom(),annonceEntity.getPrix(),annonceEntity.getDateCreation()); 
            home.list.add(prl.getPanelMain());
        });

        frame.setContentPane(home.panelMain);
        ...

    }
}
```

```java
public class ProductList {

    private JLabel title;
    private JLabel price;
    private JLabel category;
    private JLabel date;
    private JPanel panelMain;

    public ProductList(String nom, double price, Timestamp date){
        this.title.setText(nom);
        this.price.setText(String.valueOf(price));
        this.date.setText(date.toString());
    }

    public JPanel getPanelMain() {
        return panelMain;
    }
}
```

When I exectue my code my ad list is still empty :/
Do you know why ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You never add your components to the panel.

In the constructor of your ProductList class you need code like:

```
panelMain.add( title );
panelMain.add( price );
panelMain.add( date );
```